# How to make the cell wider in iOS6 iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an app which was designed for iPad and iPhone. For iPhone everything is ok but in iPad version for the iOS6 platform there is an extra space from the left and right sides of the cell - in iOS7 it's ok. You can see them in storyboards on the next screenshot:

[image]

and the sizes for the cell:

[image]

How can I remove this extra space ?

Comment: u could do it by subclassing the cell and by setting the frame

Answer (score 2):

There is little changes between IOS 6 & IOS 7 for the UITableView grouped(UITableViewCell):

**IOS6 :**

[image]

`cell.contentView` and `cell.view` is totally different with their frames .

**IOS 7 :**

[image]

`Cell.ContentView` is nothing but the Whole View of the Cell .

**IOS 6(VIEW):**
[image]

If you still wants to do with your thought then make it as `Plain Style for UITableView` OR by `Subclassing the cell`.

**NOTE**: This is not an answer for your question. Its just the way to suggest

Comment: thanks for your "way to suggest" but when I subclassing the cell - what I need to change in iOS6? frame of view or content view?

Comment: Unfortunately the cell stays the same, ok, I'll try to play with autoresize masks.. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using table type group ?

Try changing the UITableView type from group to plain.