# Table view cell can't show imageview after exported to XCode5

Tags: ios, xcode5

Here the story, before, i use xcode 4 and using library ECSSlidingView Menu, it work nicely but after i clone it to new project using xcode 5, many thing messed up, even with no code change!

the view shifted up, and the imageview isn't displayed

[image: Before]

[image: After]

both using this chunk of code (tell me if you need more)

For CellView
    @implementation SideMenuTableViewCell

```
@synthesize indexpath;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self setAccessoryCheckmarkColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self setDisclosureIndicatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self setAccessoryCheckmarkColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        // Disable this as this will overlaped with draw to stroke line
        //UIView * backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        //[backgroundView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        //[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[CustomConfiguration CFG_THEME_COLOR_BLUE]];
        //[self setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
        //
        [self setBackgroundColor:[CustomConfiguration CFG_THEME_COLOR_BLUE]];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[CustomConfiguration CFG_THEME_COLOR_YELLOW]];
        [self.textLabel setFont:[CustomConfiguration CFG_THEME_FONT_LARGEBUTTON]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
- (void)setAccessoryType:(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)accessoryType{
    [super setAccessoryType:accessoryType];
    if(accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        MMCustomCheckmark * customCheckmark = [[MMCustomCheckmark alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
        [customCheckmark setColor:self.accessoryCheckmarkColor];
        [self setAccessoryView:customCheckmark];
    }
    else if(accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator){
        MMDisclosureIndicator * di = [[MMDisclosureIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 14)];
        [di setColor:self.disclosureIndicatorColor];
        [self setAccessoryView:di];
    }
    else {
        [self setAccessoryView:nil];
    }
}
// Configure cell.imageView size and position
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 25, 25);
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    if (self.indexpath.row > 0) {
        return;
    }
    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //// Frames
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, -1, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)+1);

    UIColor *customWhite = [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:251.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0 alpha:1];    

    //// Fill Drawing

    CGRect fillRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame), CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 1);
    UIBezierPath* fillPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: fillRect];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [fillPath addClip];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    //// TopStroke Drawing
    // Do not draw top stroke unless section index is greater than 0
    if (self.indexpath.section > 0) {
        UIBezierPath* topStrokePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame)+1, CGRectGetWidth(frame), 1)];
        [customWhite setFill];
        [topStrokePath fill];
    }
    //// Highlight Drawing

    //// BottomStroke Drawing
    if (self.indexpath.row == 0) {
        UIBezierPath* bottomStrokePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 1, CGRectGetWidth(frame), 1)];
        [customWhite setFill];
        [bottomStrokePath fill];
    }
    //// Cleanup
    //CGGradientRelease(gradient2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}

@end
```

For TableView, method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuItemCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Always redraw tanle cell
    //if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SideMenuTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
    [(SideMenuTableViewCell *)cell setIndexpath:indexPath];
    //}
    cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case MMDrawerSectionAccountSection:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: {
                    cell.imageView.image = Nil;
                    cell.textLabel.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
                    break; }
                case 1: {                             
                    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.profileData valueForKey:@"firstName"], [self.profileData valueForKey:@"lastName"]]];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];
                    UILazyImageView *lazyImage = [[UILazyImageView alloc] init];
                    [lazyImage loadImageWithURL:[self.profileData valueForKey:@"photoURL"]];
                    // Resize photo profile                    
                    CGRect resizeRect;
                    resizeRect.size = cell.imageView.image.size;
                    resizeRect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
                    [lazyImage.image drawInRect:resizeRect];
                    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    cell.imageView.image = resizedImage;
                    break; }
                case 2: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_SAVEDARTICLE];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"saved.png"];
                    break; }
                case 3: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_SAVEDHOSPITAL];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"savedhospital.png"];
                    break; }
                case 4: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_LOGOUT];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"];
                    break; }
            }
            //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            break;
        case MMDrawerSectionMenuSection:{
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: {
                    cell.imageView.image = Nil;
                    cell.textLabel.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
                    break; }
                case 1: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_NEWSFEED];
                    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newsfeed.png"]];
                    break; }
                case 2: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_ARTICLE];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"article.png"];
                    break; }
                case 3: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_HOSPITAL];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinmenu"];
                    break; }
                case 4: {
                    [cell.textLabel setText:LOC_EN_SIDEMENU_PURCHASE];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purchase"];
                    break; }
            }
            //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7)

Comment: hi @Wain..I'm not following.. can you describe how it gonna be dupe?

Comment: Seconded, tell me more

Comment: Check this : few of your problem solves: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650821/how-to-make-the-cell-wider-in-ios6-ipad/20650973#20650973**
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159621/converting-ios-6-app-to-ios-7/19159882#19159882**

Comment: Thank you @KumarKl but ECSTablView didn't declared in storyboard, its all in script, so i can't really make use your suggestion, anyway thanks.

Comment: Does `cell.imageView` return nil?

Comment: Not tried, but i guess no since line "cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);" nor any other imageview method didn't throw error

Comment: @DeckyFx No error will occur if you send method to a nil object in Objective-C.

Comment: with NSLOG "%@" <UIImageView: 0x1769e950; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <AUISelectiveBordersLayer: 0x176ae230>>

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this piece of code:-- 
http://pastie.org/8703954
As well you need to set cell background colour as ClearColour..