# iOS 6 custom grouped UITableViewCell incorrect size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have created a `UITableViewCell` subclass which contains a `UITextField`. However when I add that cell to my grouped table view in iOS 6 the cell gets extended to the table view edges.

[image: The Name field is extended but the Company and Season fields are in the same tableview yet the correct size]

Here is the code for the custom cell.

```
#import "ActivityNameEditCell.h"

@implementation ActivityNameEditCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];

        [self addSubview:self.textField];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x + 10, 0, self.frame.size.width - self.contentView.frame.origin.x - 10, self.frame.size.height);
}

@end
```

This same cell class lays out correctly in iOS 7

[image]

Is there anything glaringly obvious that I've done wrong? How can I fix the cell in iOS 6?

Comment: I think `self.contentView.frame.origin.x` in `CGRectMake` causes the problem in iOS6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply forgot to call `[super layoutSubviews]` in my `layoutSubviews` implementation. Derp...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the cause due to the customised layout in your class file

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.origin.x + 10, 0, self.frame.size.width - self.contentView.frame.origin.x - 10, self.frame.size.height);
}
```

Here, `self.contentView.frame....` is comparatively  different from IOS7 .

Check my [ANSWER here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650821/how-to-make-the-cell-wider-in-ios6-ipad/20650973#20650973) for more info